# g timeout add seconds in gtk c++

Tags: c++, class, gtk, gtk2

I am creating class for display message for 10 seconds, then close the form.
I use `g_timeout_add_seconds` function for time delay. while compiling I facing the error as follows:

```
msgbox.cpp:84:72: error: invalid use of void expression 
int a = g_timeout_add_seconds(1, this->Label(i), (gpointer)this);
```

The code as follows:

```
void Msgbox::LabelUpdate(void)
{
  int i = 1;
  while(i <= 10)
  {
    g_timeout_add_seconds(1, this->Label(i), (gpointer)this);
    i++;
  }
  gtk_widget_set_sensitive(close_btn , TRUE);
  gtk_widget_grab_focus(close_btn);
}

void Msgbox::Label(int time)
{
  char buf[256];
  sprintf(buf, "<span color=\"purple\"><b> Time to wait : %d secs </b></span>", time);
  gtk_label_set_markup (GTK_LABEL(msg_lbl), buf);
}
```

Kindly Help!
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `msgbox.cpp:84:72` which line is this? Is this the whole code?

Comment: Your shown code doesn't match the error message you present. Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us, and copy-paste the full and complete build output from that example into the question. And add a comment on the line where you get the error.

Comment: With that said, what is your `Label` function returning? Does it make sense to use that result as an argument to a function call?

Answer (score 0):

Doc. of [g_timeout_add_seconds](https://people.gnome.org/%7Edesrt/glib-docs/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add-seconds):

> ```
> guint               g_timeout_add_seconds               (guint interval,
>                                                          GSourceFunc function,
>                                                          gpointer data);
> ```
>
> Sets a function to be called at regular intervals with the default priority, G_PRIORITY_DEFAULT. The function is called repeatedly until it returns FALSE, at which point the timeout is automatically destroyed and the function will not be called again.
>
> This internally creates a main loop source using g_timeout_source_new_seconds() and attaches it to the main loop context using g_source_attach(). You can do these steps manually if you need greater control. Also see g_timout_add_seconds_full().
>
> interval : the time between calls to the function, in seconds
> function : function to call
> data : data to pass to function
> Returns : the ID (greater than 0) of the event source.
>
> Since 2.14

Thereby [GSourceFunc](https://people.gnome.org/%7Edesrt/glib-docs/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#GSourceFunc) is defined as:

> ```
> gboolean            (*GSourceFunc)                      (gpointer data);
> ```
>
> Specifies the type of function passed to g_timeout_add(), g_timeout_add_full(), g_idle_add(), and g_idle_add_full().
>
> data : data passed to the function, set when the source was created with one of the above functions.
> Returns : it should return FALSE if the source should be removed.

To use `MsgBox::Label()` as second argument for `g_timeout_add_seconds()`, it must match the signature of `GSourceFunc`.

I.e. it must

- be a `static` member function
- have return type `gboolean`
- have a parameter `gpointer`.

How `MsgBox::Label()` is declared (concerning `static`) is not exposed by OP but
the signature is wrong anyway.